# Is the noun modifier "among them a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle" an appositive or absolute phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, modifiers, noun-phrases, appositives

Higgins was looking at videos coming out of the Daraya region when he noticed several weapons that he had not yet documented in Syria, ***among them a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle***.

Source- New Yorker
https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2013/11/25/rocket-man-2

It seems to me that the entire noun phrase is modifying weapons. So it cant be an absolute phrase.

Isn't a noun phrase modifying another noun an appositive

Comment: The "among them expression" is a verbless clause serving as a supplementary adjunct. We understand "among them were a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle".

Answer (score 3):

According to [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), it is a verbless clause acting as a supplement (pp. 1265-1268, 1359-1360); essentially it's similar to that [in your previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/615279/is-all-showing-that-the-weapons-were-being-used-by-the-free-syrian-army-an-abs), but we don't have a verb in the *-ing* form.

That verbless clause instead consists of a predicative complement (sometimes called a *subject complement*) "a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle" and a subject "among them." These have been reversed in order due to subject-dependent inversion (*ibid.,* pp. 1385-1386).

Comment: isn't a verbless clause a phrase?

Comment: @rahulsehrawat Yes, it is a kind of phrase.

Comment: Thanks for always giving the source and page references underpinning your answers.

Comment: *among them* is not the subject; it is a “preposed” “complement” to the subject.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Are you saying it's a complement of (and licensed by) the nouns *rocket* and *rifle*?

Comment: I’m parroting what *CGEL* is saying: “In the great majority of cases the preposed element is a complement, usually of the verb be...” In my own words, I would say that in, e.g., *Under the bed are cats*, we have an inversion, where *under the bed* is a locative complement. *Cats* is the subject.

Comment: And while some prepositional phrases can be pressed into service as a subject (*Under the bed is dark and dusty*), *among them* is not among them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you do indeed have an ***absolute phrase***:

> *Higgins was looking at videos coming out of the Daraya region when he noticed several weapons that he had not yet documented in Syria,
> **among them a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle**.*

It’s hard to see because its ***subject*** is inverted and because *being* is deleted (which we can do with absolute phrases). You can look at it like this before putting it back the way you had it:

> *He noticed several weapons that he had not yet documented in Syria, **a portable anti-tank rocket and a wheel-mounted recoilless rifle** <s>being</s> among them.*