# Is "all showing that the weapons were being used by the Free Syrian Army" an absolute?

Tags: modifiers, absolute-constructions

> At the same time, dozens of videos of the weapons were being uploaded from Daraya, ***all showing that the weapons were being used by the Free Syrian Army***

**Source-New Yorker magazine
*https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2013/11/25/rocket-man-2*

Why I think it's an absolute phrase-

The structure is in line with that of an absolute phrase,i.e noun followed by a participle, and it is modifying the main clause

Comment: What's the source of this quote? What do you think the answer is? Please expand your question.

Comment: @Laurel I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*all of which showed that the weapons were being used by the Free Syrian Army* is not an absolute phrase.

It is (in traditional grammar terms) a nonrestrictive reduced relative clause with a quantifier. You can see its function more clearly when it’s unreduced and moved next to its noun phrase:

> *At the same time, dozens of videos of the weapons, **all of which showed
> that the weapons were being used by the Free Syrian Army**, were being
> uploaded from Daraya.*

The relative clause modifies *dozens* in the noun phrase *dozen of videos of the weapons*. *All* quantifies the relative pronoun *which*, which refers to *dozens* (and which disappears in the reduction):

> *At the same time, dozens of videos of the weapons, **all showing
> that the weapons were being used by the Free Syrian Army**, were being
> uploaded from Daraya.*

Because the noun phrase is trapped at the beginning of a passive voice construction, its long relative clause is moved to the end. You can see how movement would be unnecessary in the active voice:

> *At the same time, [someone] was uploading dozens of videos of the weapons, **all showing that the weapons were being used by the Free
> Syrian Army**.*

Answer (score 2):

According to [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), it is a gerund-participial clause acting as a supplement (pp. 1265-1268, 1359-1360). It isn't quite like an ordinary absolute construction, since it's "anchored" (in their terms) to a specific noun phrase within the clause, in this case "dozens of videos of the weapons," which it serves to describe.